# Reemplazar una columna de un archivo usando referencia de otro archivo (bash)

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Tengo un **archivo1** de dos columnas:

```
1:1000:A:G           rs1234

1:2345:C:T           rs321
```

Y otro **archivo2** con 18 columnas:

```
1:1000_A_G 1 100019544 A G 0.0172 0.0465 0.7114 +--+ 6133 0 2.828 3 0.4189 A_G A G 1:1000:A:G

1:2345_C_T 1 100019544 C T 0.0172 0.0465 0.7114 +--+ 6133 0 2.828 3 0.4189 C_T C T 1:2345:C:T
```

y necesito reemplazar la última columna del **archivo2** con la referencia adecuada del *archivo 1*, de forma que quede un **output:**

```
1:1000_A_G 1 100019544 A G 0.0172 0.0465 0.7114 +--+ 6133 0 2.828 3 0.4189 A_G A G rs1234

1:2345_C_T 1 100019544 C T 0.0172 0.0465 0.7114 +--+ 6133 0 2.828 3 0.4189 C_T C T rs321
```

Comment: ¿eso es un ejercició que debemos realizar?  ¿tu que has hecho al respecto?  ¿puedes ponerlo en la pregunta para que veamos lo que has intentado y podamos corregirte y ayudarte?  Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y como realizar buenas preguntas para obtener buenas respuestas, gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Tenemos este `archivo1`

```
$ cat archivo1
1:1000:A:G rs1234
1:2345:C:T rs321
```

y este `archivo2`

```
cat archivo2
1:1000_A_G 1 100019544 A G 0.0172 0.0465 0.7114 +--+ 6133 0 2.828 3 0.4189 A_G A G 1:1000:A:G
1:2345_C_T 1 100019544 C T 0.0172 0.0465 0.7114 +--+ 6133 0 2.828 3 0.4189 C_T C T 1:2345:C:T
```

Usando `awk` podemos hacer esto:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($NF in a) {$NF=a[$NF]} 1' archivo1 archivo2
1:1000_A_G 1 100019544 A G 0.0172 0.0465 0.7114 +--+ 6133 0 2.828 3 0.4189 A_G A G rs1234
1:2345_C_T 1 100019544 C T 0.0172 0.0465 0.7114 +--+ 6133 0 2.828 3 0.4189 C_T C T rs321
```

- En `awk`, `FNR` se refiere al número de registro (generalmente el número de línea) en el archivo actual.
- `NR` se refiere al número de registro total.
- El operador `==` es un operador de comparación, que devuelve verdadero cuando los dos operandos son iguales.
- `NR == FNR` es una condición que sólo se evalúa como verdadera para el primer archivo.
- La acción `{a[$1]=$2;next}` guarda todo el primer archivo, línea por línea, en el array o matriz asociativa cuyo objetivo es buscar los valores de la segunda columna del primer archivo en base a la  los valores correspondientes de la primera columna. Con `next` awk pasa a procesar el siguiente archivo, aquí `archivo2`.
- `($NF in a)` si el último campo del `archivo2` está en el array `a` entonces se realiza esta acción `{$NF=a[$NF]}`, es decir, asignamos a `$NF` el valor `a[$NF]` que es el contenido del campo 2 del `archivo1`

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción, con perl.

```
perl -ane '$X{$F[0]}=$F[1] if @F<3 or print s/\S+$/$X{$&}/re' archivo1 archivo2
```

Con la opción `-a` los campos se guardan automáticamente en el array `@F`

Si el número de campos es menor a 3, estamos en el primer fichero. En tal caso guardamos la pareja clave-valor en el hash `X`.

Después usamos este hash en una expresión regular para eliminar la última columna y remplazarla por ese valor.

Answer (score 0):

Usando `join` en `bash` (y procurando que los archivos esten ordenados)

```
join -1 1 -2 18 '-o 2.'{1..17} -o 1.2 archivo1 archivo2
```

producirá el resultado deseado

```
1:1000_A_G 1 100019544 A G 0.0172 0.0465 0.7114 +--+ 6133 0 2.828 3 0.4189 A_G A G rs1234
1:2345_C_T 1 100019544 C T 0.0172 0.0465 0.7114 +--+ 6133 0 2.828 3 0.4189 C_T C T rs321
```